# Why do some FTP Clients not connect to a IIS7 FTP Server?

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2008-r2, filezilla, dreamweaver, iis-7

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server with II7.  I have installed the FTP server.  I can connect to it fine with Dreamweaver CS5 on my Mac.  I can connect to it fine with Cute FTP 7 Professional on a PC.  I cannot connect to it with Filezilla on the Mac.  With Filezilla the operation times out after a while.  Some of my clients cannot connect to it no matter what FTP client they try.  We've been over the connection credentials (host, username & password) and are pretty certain they are all correct.

Can anyone shed some light on this situation.  I do note that the programs that I can connect with are older.  Perhaps there are some advanced security settings on newer clients?  The settings I use are connecting via FTP, port 21, basic authentication ... a bunch of other setting that I do not understand.

Filezilla Logs (which doesn't connect):

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.steadyserve.net
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xxx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER xxxxxx
Response:   331 Password required for pedroo.
Command:    PASS *******
Response:   230 User logged in.
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 Windows_NT
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Extended features supported:
Response:    LANG EN*
Response:    UTF8
Response:    AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
Response:    PBSZ
Response:    PROT C;P;
Response:    CCC
Response:    HOST
Response:    SIZE
Response:    MDTM
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:   211 END
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/pedroo" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   425 Cannot open data connection.
Command:    PORT 10,0,0,8,210,49
Response:   200 PORT command successful.
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Dreamweaver logs (which does connect):

```
< 220 Microsoft FTP Service
 > USER pedroo
 < 331 Password required for pedroo.
 > PASS
 < 230 User logged in.
 > PWD
 < 257 "/pedroo" is current directory.
 > PWD
 < 257 "/pedroo" is current directory.
 > CWD /pedroo
 < 250 CWD command successful.
 > PWD
 < 257 "/pedroo" is current directory.
 > CWD /pedroo
 < 250 CWD command successful.
 > PORT 10,0,0,8,211,100
 < 200 PORT command successful.
 > TYPE A
 < 200 Type set to A.
```

I've tried changing the mode form passive to active.  I get the same error.

TIA,

Jay

Comment: Can you include a relevant snippet of logs from each client?

Comment: I will edit the question with the logs.  Thanks!

Comment: Try turning on Filezilla's debug logging (Edit->Settings->Debug) This will give you much more information about what FZ is doing and where it is failing.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be a port issue.  I found the answer here: http://superuser.com/search?q=ftp+can%27t+retrieve+directory+listing.  Note NOT an ISS/Apache issue, UltraDEVV.  The log files were helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to help without seeing logs.

But my wild guess is that the working clients use different (possibly active) transfer mode than the non-working (passive).

You will get a better answer, once you share the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer already posted here:
[FileZilla FTP to AWS EC2 Windows Server 2012 Instance: Failed to retrieve directory listing](https://superuser.com/questions/811527/filezilla-ftp-to-aws-ec2-windows-server-2012-instance-failed-to-retrieve-direct)

It was a port issue.  The log files were helpful to look at and helped me narrow it down.

Comment: Which answer specifically?

Comment: Sorry, I copied the incorrect URL above.  This is the answer: http://superuser.com/questions/811527/filezilla-ftp-to-aws-ec2-windows-server-2012-instance-failed-to-retrieve-direct