# Google Cloud - Filezilla FTP to compute engine running Plesk

Tags: networking, firewall, ftp, plesk, google-compute-engine

With my current set up I have a Google Cloud compute engine machine running Debian and Plesk 12.5. The hosting, web space (https) etc... all work. However, I am having some issues trying to use FTP.

Using plain text FTP my connection keeps hanging on the "Retrieving directory listing..."

```
Status: Resolving address of domain.com
Status: Connecting to IPADDRESS:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
```

If I use FTP over TLS I get unroutable address.

```
Status: Resolving address of domain.com
Status: Connecting to IPADDRESS:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
```

trouble shooting #1
Opened all ports i could see in the logs for FTP on Google cloud firewall and on Plesk firewall.

trouble shooting #2
Made sure the external IP address of server was correct and static

trouble shooting #3
After some searching I found i should use passive FTP with use servers public IP address enabled however, this didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FileZilla FTP to AWS EC2 Windows Server 2012 Instance: Failed to retrieve directory listing](http://superuser.com/questions/811527/filezilla-ftp-to-aws-ec2-windows-server-2012-instance-failed-to-retrieve-direct)

Comment: Looked at that and don't think it applies, i can already connect via a rsa key pair and SFTP to the cloud machine using the IP address. When i do this the website folders are not available to me (file permissions). And i dont want to connect to the machines IP and file system. Id rather log in with mywebsite.com and go to its directory to avoid messing files and permissions up.

I have also already set filezilla to passive and to use external IP address (see #3).

Comment: Well, Ok.While I've misunderstood that you use FileZilla server, still the problem is that your FTP server (whatever that is) does not know its external IP address. If you'd bother to tell us what your FTP server is, we could tell you the right steps to configure it.

Comment: ermmm what? i said in the opening paragraph that my server is Debain with Plesk 12.5 and i am connecting to it via Filezilla? So i did "bother". And on top of this i have checked the settings in Plesk and it states the external IP address (#2) so its FTP server should see this.

Comment: I mean what's your FTP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, additional passive ports needed to be opened. In addition to this, Plesk FTP component had to be changed to passive ports.

as per the guide found at [Plesk Knowledge base](https://kb.plesk.com/1240) accessed 07/08/2016

> Add passive port range to config file, load ip_conntrack_ftp module into the system and...

```
Make sure that you have the following line in the iptables settings:

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

If the server is behind a NAT, the ip_nat_ftp module should also be loaded:

# /sbin/modprobe ip_nat_ftp
```